# SQL How to perform multiple look-ups from a list, in one query

Tags: sql, select, group-by, pivot

We have a weird database table (wt) for which I can construct a query that can return a single row with these fields:

wt.thing_a_id = 5, wt.thing_b_id = 12, wt.thing_c_id = 9

Then, there's another lookup table (dt) that holds descriptions for these numbers, you could imagine it like this:

```
id   desc
5    "flour"
12   "cups"
9    "barley"
```

what I need to end up with is numbers from wt, along with its description from dt.

I can do 3 simple queries, one to look up each of my three thing_ values (select desc from dt where id = )  but I was hoping to do it all in one query.

Is there a way to do this?

Even better, is there way to do my query to get my single row of thing id's *and* combine them with their descriptions?  I think the fundamental problem/challenge is that my thing id's are not one per row, but that they come back as fields in just one row. This makes it really hard to join against them, for example.

Michael

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want conditional aggregation:

```
select
    max(case when id = 3  then descr end) descr_3,
    max(case when id = 12 then descr end) descr_12,
    max(case when id = 9  then descr end) descr_9
from dt
where id in (3, 12, 9)
```

Note that `desc` is a SQL keyword, hence a poor choice for a column name. I renamed it `descr` in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I love to play with common table expressions (CTE), this is an ideal candidate for one.

In the example below, decriptions and dataset are substitutes for the actual tables you use. I am just building them in memory rather than an actual table.

In the "breakdown" CTE I am splitting up the CSV value from dataset into multiple rows.

In the last part of the select I am converting everything after the = sign to a number, and then matching that on id from the descriptions CTE. The resulting dataset is I believe what you requested.

```
WITH
    descriptions AS
        (SELECT 5 AS id, 'flour' AS description FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 12 AS id, 'cups' AS description FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 9 AS id, 'barley' AS description FROM DUAL),
    dataset AS
        (SELECT 'wt.thing_a_id = 5, wt.thing_b_id = 12, wt.thing_c_id = 9' AS result FROM DUAL),
    breakdown ( result, REMAINDER ) AS
        (SELECT TRIM( SUBSTR( result
                            , 1
                            , INSTR( result || ',', ',' ) - 1 ) )                   AS result
              , TRIM( SUBSTR( result, INSTR( result || ',', ',' ) + 1 ) || ',' )    AS REMAINDER
           FROM dataset
         UNION ALL
         SELECT TRIM( SUBSTR( REMAINDER
                            , 1
                            , INSTR( REMAINDER, ',' ) - 1 ) )
              , SUBSTR( REMAINDER, INSTR( REMAINDER || ',', ',' ) + 1 )     AS REMAINDER
           FROM breakdown
          WHERE REMAINDER IS NOT NULL)
SELECT result, TO_NUMBER( TRIM( SUBSTR( result, INSTR( result, '=' ) + 1 ) ) ) AS id, description
  FROM breakdown
       LEFT OUTER JOIN descriptions
           ON TO_NUMBER( TRIM( SUBSTR( breakdown.result, INSTR( breakdown.result, '=' ) + 1 ) ) ) =
              descriptions.id
```

Results:

```
Result              ID  DESCRIPTION
wt.thing_a_id = 5   5   flour
wt.thing_b_id = 12 12   cups
wt.thing_c_id = 9   9   barley
```